# Signing Android APPs for one company with different providers

Tags: android, google-play, apk, sign, android-keystore

Our company currently has several APPs for Android in Google Play Store, developed by different software providers.

What would be the best approach for this situation? 
Having one keystore for all the APPs from our company?
Having one keystore for each provider? For each APP?

What would be the main benefits and drawbacks from each approach?

Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

In my opinion having one keystore for each provider will be better approach in this situation. Afterall it is signing and instead of signing all the apps with one keystore, multiple signs will be better. However, if your company have 200 apps with 100 different provider then it would be unwise to have different keys. It is about your scale and choice. Yet, i don't think there will be so much difference between two approach.

Comment: Actually it's just 3 apps and 2 providers for the moment, but it can grow in the future. Our older provider is not happy about sharing current keystore with our newer provider due to security reasons. I assume they are right on this so we were thinking on using different keystores for each provider.

Comment: Yeah it is much safer way to continue, and i think it's around manageable numbers.

Answer (score 0):

You can use flavor for different-different app version and app.

Answer (score 0):

- I would STRONGLY recommend having a different certificate for each app.
- I would also STRONGLY recommend using [Google Play App Signing](https://support.google.com/googleplay/android-developer/answer/7384423) rather than signing the app yourself.

The benefits of the first case is future commercial flexibility. App developers often want to sell their app to another company, spin off a division to a separate company, or separate responsibility for app signing keys so they don't have a single point of failure. If you have a single key then:

- If you sell the app to another company then you have to give them the signing key and they can sign any of your apps, thereby producing fake versions
- if you want to spin out a division the same problem occurs
- if you want one team to be able to sign their own app for testing, then they can sign any app for the company.

Having a separate key solves all these issues.

If you want to know why you should use Google Play app signing you should search StackOverflow for questions saying things like "help I have lost my signing key/password/had a computer stolen, what can I do?". There are hundreds of them, and the problem has hit even some of the biggest developers. If you use Google Play App Signing then Google Play will keep your key safe, and Google Play support can help you if you lose it.

To comment on the answer that cites [the Android Studio page](https://support.google.com/googleplay/android-developer/answer/7384423) they misunderstand it. That is just about having a single signing key per app, not across apps.

There are some reasons to use the same signing key for multiple apps. On the Android system this gives the apps some abilities to trust each other in certain ways on things like RPCs, but it is very rare to need this.